# What equivalent license for CC SA without BY? Share-alike but no attribution

Tags: licensing, creative-commons

I would like to publish my pictures, and the license that I like most is CC BY-SA... except that I don't care about attribution.

So, what license should I use?
Requirements:

- Exactly like CC BY-SA 3.0 but not requiring attribution
- English language, translations available
- The best well-known the better

If several licenses satisfy these requirements, the winner will be picked by Google fight.

Non-solutions:

- CC-SA looks perfect but [its page](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/sa/1.0/) says:
  "*This license is retired. Do not use for new works.*"
- GFDL is burdensome when [printing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GFDL#Burdens_when_printing) so it won't do either.

Comment: So the attribution should only contain a reference to the license, but not your name or the URL to your work? What about indiciation of modifications to your work?

Comment: Make a custom license.

Comment: @JohnMiliter: Unfortunately, that does not quite fit the second and third requirements ;-)

Comment: Though I do wish that they didn't decide to retire CC-SA.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the [Public Domain Mark, CC0](http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/), ([longer details](https://wiki.creativecommons.org/wiki/Public_domain)), except is doesn't include the Share-Alike

> When a work is in the public domain, it is free for use by anyone for any purpose without restriction under copyright law. Public domain is the purest form of open/free, since no one owns or controls the material in any way.